# Shortest path without exceeding a fixed number of edges

Tags: shortest-path

My problem is to find the shortest path between two edges (`source`, `end`) without exceeding a number of edges.

If we have the following arcs:

```
test 1 : from s--to---a--to--b--to---e cost is 2
test 2 : s-----d-----e  cost is  3 
test 3 : s----p-----e  cost is  4 
test 4 : s-----e  cost is  9
```

Suppose `k` equals 4, then the answer is 2 (s-a-b-e : number of edges is 4 not greater than `k`), but if `k` equals 3, the answer is 3 because number of edges is 3, not greater than `k`, and so on.

Can someone help me to get the solution?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit. You probably mean "between two *vertices*" and not "between two edges". Also, you have to show what you tried so far and how it failed; currently, you're just asking for somebody else to do your work.

Comment: actually i didn't find at least the idea until i can show you what i failed about so i posted it to get some solution and by the way it's not home work in fact i like programming and i practice it in many  sites like Online Judge and while i'm trying to get the solution of some problems i found this and i couldn't get the solution can you help me please

Comment: You could start with looking into shortest path algorithms such as [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).